# Read bulk data (Dynamic query) from Database and write to flat file using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to read a bulk data from database, the query to read the tables will be dynamic (table name will be chosen from the config file). and wite the data in a flatfile with a delimiter. As the table name itself dynamic, I cant go with any rowmapper/DTO/VO classes.

Which is reading a custom data and writing it to the flat file with some delimiter.

Can you help to identify how we can achieve this with spring batch.

Answer (score 0):

Write your custom reader implementing ItemStreamReader. Read the config file in the open() method and set the table name as a global variable. read() method you can write the query to fetch the record using the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RowMapper` that writes to a `Map` and use the `Map` as the item returned.